# cut text file and get the last field following a delimeter

Tags: shell, crop, cut

I'm having problem to cut/crop the begining of each file line until a delimiter using the cut command.

But doesn't worked.

I've a file full of lines like that :

```
202008/AX/20200818/20200818_043714rs1fif06.dat:FG0620200817FR1      RCRGBRJ360100000000000115600000003470000000416340000000693900000013878
```

I want to cut the begining of the line to leave as exit

```
FG0620200817FR1         RCRGBRJ360100000000000115600000003470000000416340000000693900000013878
```

I thought to use ':' or 'rs1fif06.dat' as delimiters. Using the following cut command :

```
cut -d':' filename
```

That's doesn't worked and i don't know why.
or

```
cut -d'rs1fif06.dat:' filename
```

That's doesn't worked as i read because cut command doesn't allow such words as delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut` tells you what you have to do:

```
$ cut -d:
cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
```

So leave the second field.

```
cut -d: -f2
```